# no printing after python script, with no errors

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

No errors just not printing the results. it is supposed to print out headlines from the url. the script runs but returns nothing whilst parsing for `balancedheadlines`. i can swap the tag i look for to p and return data but i believe i am no passing through the tags correctly to retrieve just the headlines.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.nytimes.com'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')


for ap in soup.find_all('h2', attrs = {"class" : "balancedheader"}):

    if ap.a:
        print(ap.a.text.replace(".n/", " "))
    else:
        print(ap.strip)
```

Comment: There is no `h2` tag with the `balancedheader` class present in the DOM.

Comment: `soup.find_all('h2', attrs = {"class" : "balancedheader"}) == []` . Because its an empty list your loop that is supposed to run for every item in the list, does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said `he script runs but returns nothing whilst parsing for balancedheadlines` but trying to search `balancedheader` . There is no balancedheader in your site.You can see all h2 tags like :

```
h2_tags = soup.findAll('h2')
for allh2 in h2_tags:
    print allh2
```

Above code will return all `h2` tags in your website.

I think you are trying to get title in `balancedHeadline` and its in `Javascript` so you need to use `Selenium` :

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'your driver path')
driver.get('https://www.nytimes.com/2019/02/24/world/europe/pope-vatican-sexual-abuse.html')

x = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span[class='balancedHeadline']")

for title in x:
    print title.text
driver.close()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Pope Francis Ends Landmark Meeting by Calling for ‘All-Out Battle’ to Fight Sexual Abuse
```

Answer (score 1):

[NY Times](https://www.nytimes.com/) web site has no 'h2' element with class named 'balancedheader'.

The xpath '//h2[@class='balancedheader']' return an empty set.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed you issue, you are not indenting correctly and when you import something make sure the 'i' in "import" is not capital. Fixed Version:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.nytimes.com'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')


for ap in soup.find_all('h2', attrs = {"class" : "balancedheader"}):
    if ap.a:
        print(ap.a.text.replace(".n/", " "))
    else:
        print(ap.strip)
```

Comment: capitol was just a typo from transferring to stack. sadly this does not correct the problem.

Comment: what about the indents?